# Crosstab Query Month YTD

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a solution to convert the individual monthly averages to monthly averages from the beginning of the year. In other words from January to said month.

I used the cross tab wizard to group the rating of an employee into months in the column header. Employees are in the row header. The values of the ratings is then averaged.

My issue is this just shows the average rating of an employee for each month. I need a solution that would show me the average of each month if it included all results from the begging of the year (i.e. February would include January's and February's ratings).

```
TRANSFORM Avg(CSS_Table.[Emp_Rating]) AS AvgOfEmp_Rating
SELECT CSS_Table.[Emp]
FROM Rating_Table
GROUP BY Rating_Table.[Emp]
PIVOT Format([Survey_Date],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy to attack this

1. Create one query for each month that calculates the monthly YTD Average.
2. Create a Union query that joins them all together (i.e. make sure to use the same column names for each query).

Feed the union query into the Pivot.